# Background Incoming call and message notification is not receiving in Android Q-Municate

Tags: java, android, quickblox, quickblox-android, q-municate

I modified Q-municate powered by QuickBlox (which is open source) GitHub code. But, in this app Voip is not working. when i open the application then only I can receive call and message notification. So how to show incoming call screen when app will be close and phone screen lock. How to solve this issue perfectly?

Comment: you have any code to show?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal logic of Q-municate. If you want to show incoming call screen you need add this logic. For it you need add login to the chat in background when push was received in class [ChatNotificationHelper.java](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android/blob/master/Q-municate_app/src/main/java/com/quickblox/q_municate/utils/helpers/notification/ChatNotificationHelper.java#L60). You can see QuickBlox's [sample-videochat-webrtc](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc) for learning how to show incoming call screen when push was received.

Comment: I am modifying qmunicate app provided by quickblox and according to quickblox documentation they have added firebase notification service for notifications and they have asked to add Google API key in quickblox admin panel and Google project key in project and I have done both things and after that I have checked new users are getting subscribed to firebase notifications but still I am not receiving notifications.

Comment: please see comment of RomanPronin in thread https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android/issues/244